# Partition 500Gb SSD AFTER windows 10 install

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

ok I know this is backwards but after spending half a day doing a clean install of Windows and updating drivers I'd prefer to not have to repeat the process.

I'd like to simply partition my SSD in half. Can I do this properly AFTER having already installed windows? is there a recommended(no malware) 3rd party app that can accomplish this?

Comment: Use Disk Manager to shrink the partition then create new partition based on the unallocated space that is created.  [Shrink a Basic Volume](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731894%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [Resize a Partition for Free in Windows 7, 8.x, 10, or Vista] (http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still partition your SSD after an install is finished. You can do this through Disk Management which is natively built into Windows.. In Windows 10, you can right click on your Desktop and select `Disk Management`. Once in Disk Management, you'll right click on your drive and select `Shrink Volume`. You can then choose how much you want to shrink it. This will create unallocated space that you can right click on and create a new `Simple Volume`. You can then assign it a letter for the drive and it will go through the formatting process for you.

Here is a simple [guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/172580/how-to-create-a-separate-data-partition-for-windows/) with some pictures that can help guide you along the way.

Comment: You took the time to include a link in your answer, but not enough time, to include the information from the article in the answer you thought was relevant.  Take a minute and read your question without the link, does it answer the question?, if it does then reference link really isn't required.  Please don't reply to this comment, my only response, will be a suggestion to read the help center on this topic.  Screenshots are also helpful.